# Is this pattern of coding in react.js right?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import Connect from './connect.svg'
import Explore from './explore.svg' 

export const SomeComponent = props => {
    const someArray = [
        {text: "first", image: Connect},
        {text: "second", image: Explore}
    ]

    return ( 
        <div> 
            {someArray.map(item => (
                <img src={item.image} alt="some text" />
                <div> {item.text} </div>  
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

I have used this method of setting an image property in objects to the corresponding images I imported, and then looping all through to output things like `<li>` etc. Everything seems to work fine but I want to confirm whether this is a bad way to code or not.

Comment: Looks all right, though I'd prefer to declare the array outside the component, since it never changes

Comment: Yes, basically, using .map to render items of array is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's a good component. However, I think that to render both `<img>` and `<div>` element as siblings you may need to group them as children of a *Fragment* (eg. `<>` `</>`). Finally, its a good practice to specify a key. The example below has the suggested changes.

```js
import Connect from "./connect."
import Connect from './connect.svg'
import Explore from './explore.svg' 

export const SomeComponent = props => {
    const someArray = [
        {text: "first", image: Connect},
        {text: "second", image: Explore}
    ]
    return ( 
        <div> 
           { someArray.map ((item, key) => (
            <>
                <img src={item.image} alt="some text" key={key}/>
                <div key={key}> {item.text} </div>  
            </>
            )}} 
        </div>
    )

}
```

I hope that my opinion will be helpful.

Comment: you probably need a key like this:
            <div key={uuid}>
                <img src={item.image} alt="some text" key={key}/>
                <div key={key}> {item.text} </div>  
            </div>
It is better to move the array out of this component and pass the array to this component as a props. it is easier to this the pure function without data side of it.